# How could I replace XML <br /> with a linebreak using the Javascript Excel API

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I have a spreadsheet that has multiple cells containing XML formatting that I want to remove. The problem is that I can't just remove a linebreak since it ruins the formatting of the text. How can I replace the `<br />` with a linebreak?

```
function run() {
  return Excel.run(function(context) {
    const sheet1 = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    const sheet2 = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet2");
    const sourceCell = sheet1.getCell(1,1).load("text") 
    const destinationCell = sheet2.getCell(1,1)

    return context.sync().then(function() {
      destinationCell.values = sourceCell.text
    })
  })
}
```

Let's say my sourceCell contains the following text:

```
[["08:00 - 08:30 brushing teeth<br />08:30 - 09:00 eating breakfast<br />09:00 - 09:30 ride the bus"]]
```

How would I go about replacing the `<br />`with a linebreak in the destination cell?

Answer (score 0):

`range.values` accepts a 2d array, so you could parse the string and cut it by `<br />`, assign it to string array

```
  let mytexts : string[][];
  // logic to cut the string based on <br/>
  destinationCell.values = mytexts;
```